# Parsing error: Identifier 'setValues' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code

I've found similar questions/answers to this error message and I can see where the 'setValues' is declared within the code but I'm unsure of what/how to change. Below is the code, any addtl eyes or advice is greatly appreciated!

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";

export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    firstName:"",
    lastName:"",
    email:"",
  });
  const [submitted, setValues] = useState(false);
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

  const handleFirstNameInputChange = (event) => {
    setValues({...values, firstName: event.target.value})
  }
  const handleLastNameInputChange = (event) => {
    setValues({...values, lastName: event.target.value})
  }
  const handleEmailInputChange = (event) => {
    setValues({...values, email: event.target.value})
  }
```

Comment: Change `const [submitted, setValues] = useState(false);` to `const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);`. You have declared `setValues` twice

Comment: Changing the second instance of `setValues` to `setSubmitted` seems like it would be more consistent.

Comment: thanks! I thought that might be it, but admitedly was hesitant to make the change for fear of breaking something...thanks for confirming what I should've trusted my gut to change!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

const [submitted, **setValues**] = useState(false);

const [values, **setValues**] = useState({
firstName:"",
lastName:"",
email:"",
});

You are declaring same variable twice (See bold text)